# How to merge many datasets based on many criteria

Tags: r, database, merge

I have a main dataset and 3 others datasets over three years(data2015 for year 2015, data2016 for year 2016 and data2017 for year 2017)

```
maindata<-data.frame(ID=rep(1:3,3),Year=c(rep("2015",3),rep("2016",3),rep("2017",3)),Age=c(20,32,40,33,12,43,25,27,18))
data2015<-data.frame(ID=1:5,value=c(10,20,30,40,50))
data2016<-data.frame(ID=1:4,value=c(10,20,40,50))
data2017<-data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,5),value=c(10,30,40,70))
```

I am looking for the shortest way for merging the last 3 datasets to the main dataset in order to have such dataset below:

```
   ID  Year value    Age
1  1   2015    10    20
2  2   2015    20    32
3  3   2015    30    40
4  1   2016    10    33
5  2   2016    20    12
6  3   2016    40    43
7  1   2017    10    25
8  2   2017    30    27
9  3   2017    40    18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another base R option

```
datalist <- mget(ls(pattern = "data\\d+"))
merge(maindata,
  do.call(
    rbind,
    Map(function(x, v) within(x, Year <- v), datalist, gsub("\\D", "", names(datalist)))
  ),
  by = c("ID", "Year")
)
```

which gives

```
  ID Year Age value
1  1 2015  20    10
2  1 2016  33    10
3  1 2017  25    10
4  2 2015  32    20
5  2 2016  12    20
6  2 2017  27    30
7  3 2015  40    30
8  3 2016  43    40
9  3 2017  18    40
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df = list(data2015, data2016, data2017) %>% 
  set_names(2015:2017) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "Year")

maindata %>%   
  left_join(df, by = c("ID", "Year"))
```

```
# ID Year Age value
# 1 2015  20    10
# 2 2015  32    20
# 3 2015  40    30
# 1 2016  33    10
# 2 2016  12    20
# 3 2016  43    40
# 1 2017  25    10
# 2 2017  27    30
# 3 2017  18    40
```

Comment: your codes give me a dataset with 3 times as many lines

Comment: After removing duplicate values, still have 15 observations, Is there a problem with the value?

Comment: Yes, I need the values for only ID 1, 2 and 3 over the 3 years.

Comment: I got it wrong before. Need to use the year information in file names.

Answer (score 1):

From the expected output it looks like you want to add a new column to `maindata`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

bind_cols(maindata, map_df(mget(ls(pattern = 'data\\d+')), ~
       filter(.x, ID %in% unique(maindata$ID))) %>%
       select(-ID))

#  ID Year value
#1  1 2015    10
#2  2 2015    20
#3  3 2015    30
#4  1 2016    10
#5  2 2016    20
#6  3 2016    40
#7  1 2017    10
#8  2 2017    30
#9  3 2017    40
```

In base R, that can be done by  :

```
cbind(maindata, do.call(rbind, lapply(mget(ls(pattern = 'data\\d+')), function(x) 
                        subset(x, ID %in% unique(maindata$ID))))[-1])
```